# Cloud Run: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a containerized node-typescript-express app to cloud run but I am unable to do so, receiving the following error:

`The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080`

Here is my Dockerfile config:

```
FROM node:18.13.0 as base

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . .

FROM base as production

ENV NODE_PATH=./dist

RUN npm run build
```

In my code, I'm declaring port as

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

I also have a `.env` file where I was setting port, but I deleted the port key - as far as I know, GCP cloud run injects the port variable anyway.

Here is a screenshot from my project settings on GCP. I uploaded my image by building it locally with `docker-compose build`, tagging it, and uploading it to the GCP container repository.

[image]

I've tried manually setting the port in the code, removing the env file completely, specifying a different port, etc. I'm not even sure if the port is specifically the error and it's just some kind of catch-all.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "weather-service",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "small node server that fetches openweather api data",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 18.12 <19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=./dist node dist/src/index.js",
    "clean": "rimraf coverage dist tmp",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts",
    "prebuild": "npm run lint",
    "build": "ttsc -p tsconfig.release.json",
    "build:watch": "ttsc -w -p tsconfig.release.json",
    "build:release": "npm run clean && ttsc -p tsconfig.release.json",
    "test": "jest --coverage --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts --ext .mts && tsc",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .ts --ext .mts",
    "prettier": "prettier --config .prettierrc --write .",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
```

And lastly, here's my docker-compose file and how I'm executing the commands

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  weather-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
    volumes:
      - ./src:/home/node/app/src
    container_name: weather-service
    expose:
      - '8080'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    command: npm run dev
```

`docker-compose.prod.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  weather-service:
    build:
      target: production
    command: npm run start
```

`docker.compose.dev.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  weather-service:
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - ${PORT}
      - ${WEATHER_API_KEY}
```

`Makefile`

```
up:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up

up-prod:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up

down: 
    docker-compose down

build:
    docker-compose build
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I managed to get it successfully deployed by changing my docker-compose files to a template I found on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/MatthewCYLau/node-express-typescript)

My docker knowledge is minimal so if anyone has any idea why my old docker-compose wasn't working, I'd love to know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).